# How do I make two meshes snap together in uv image editor?

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

[image: They look identical!][image: They don't match up!]I modelled an egg and for some reason one half of the egg mesh is a little bit different to the other half as they don’t quite match up when place on top of each other. I want to make them look exactly the same so I can place them on top of each other to texture paint. Is this possible to do and how would I do it?

The meshes look identical but when placed on top of eachother

They don't quite match up ^

Comment: Could you post some screenshots here or blend file: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: @LukeD it isn't working?

Comment: What is not working? Be more descriptive and/or provide before mentioned files.

Comment: @LukeD there you go I updated my question with pictures.

Comment: There aren't any meshes in UV map. There are coordinates of vertices in UV space which will control texture placement. In order UV islands to be the same meshes have to be identical, otherwise map can be edited with e.g. snapping vertices in islands onto each other. The easiest way to avoid editing it manually is to add Mirror modifier and to mirror mesh again with U and V options in modifier settings unchecked.